# Pick out compact sets

Tags: real-analysis

a.$\{(z_1,z_2)\in \mathbb C\times \mathbb C:z_1^2+z_2^2=1\}$

b.the closure of the unit ball of $C^1[0,1]$ in $C[0,1]$

c.unit sphere in $\ell_2$

a. is not compact since it is not bounded.

c. is  not compact since I can find $e_n\in \ell_2$ which will not have any convergent subsequence.Am I correct.But

b. I cant solve.How to do it?

Comment: $C^1[0,1]$ is infinite dimensional.The closed unit ball of infinte dimensional spaces is never compact![here](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%27s_lemma) same story for $\ell_2$.

Comment: can u please explain the reasons

Comment: It basically follows from Riesz's lemma.